# Google Maps API key error on some networks

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a web application that's using Google Maps Javascript v3.  I have an API key.  Everything works fine, on *some* networks, but on some networks, it gives me an API key error.  I've set everything correctly in the allowed refers but no luck.  It is failing when I go to the Regus business lounge and use their wifi.  It's also failing for my testers in Korea.  It works on all the other networks I have tried.  I'm going crazy and I can't figure out what's wrong here.  Any ideas or any way of debugging this?

Comment: Google maps JavaScript API v3 does not require an API key.

Comment: Are the places where it is failing accessing the exact same domain as the places that work?  Are the places where it is failing behind any kind of firewall or using a proxy?